# Find and Replace File Utility

Tags: windows, file-management

I have a structure of folders, each containing a file with the same name "Client - Document.docx". Is there a utility or expedient method (running Windows XP) to replace each of these files with an updated version of the file beyond 120 CTRL+C,Vs?

For raw commands, please explain what the syntax is, and the switches used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assuming the existing files are called doc1.doc, and
- assuming the new file is called doc1.doc and is in the current directory, and
- assuming the file tree starts in Dir1

  `for /r Dir1 %a in (doc1.doc) do copy /y doc1.doc %~pa\doc1.doc`
  You will need quotes around any file names with spaces.

FYI -
`For /r Dir1 in (doc1.doc)` tells "for" to search subdirectories of Dir1 for doc1.doc and put each file found in the %a variable.

`copy /y` says replace without asking

`%~pa1` is the path only component of the %a variable.

Run this for a non-destructive look at what might happen

`for /r Dir1 %a in (doc1.doc) do echo %~pa\doc1.doc`

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the syntax is, and the switches used?